# How to change highlight color for Checkstyle warnings in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, checkstyle

In Eclipse Checkstyle is throwing a warning for a method that has not JavaDoc comment. This is fine, but I have a dark theme and the text is being highlighted with a bright yellow that looks horrendous and makes the text very hard to read. Where do I change this highlighting color?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Under Window -> Preferences, go to General -> Editors -> Text Editors -> Annotations. There you can select "Checkstyle warning" from the list and change the color to a darker one that hurts the eyes less.

Source: https://sourceforge.net/p/eclipse-cs/discussion/274376/thread/888a621f/